# Does number of requests to a web service is (number of instances * number of calls per instance)

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, webservice-client

We recently tried to replicate hundreds of requests per second to our webservice. Web service has oracle DB connection string as below.

```
Data Source=urOracle;User Id=urUsername;Password=urPassword;Min Pool Size=0;Connection Lifetime=120;Max Pool Size =200;
```

To achieve the above mentioned, we created a small application which hits the webservice and gets the results. This is a Console application.

```
Parallel.For(0,100,RunMethod())
```

Code inside RunMethod:

```
public void RunMethod()
{
    string sth = SoapCall().Result;
    Console.WriteLine(sth);
}
public Task<String> SoapCall()
{
    //Code for soap call
}
```

And we created another small console application, which just invokes the above exe 100 times.

```
for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    Process.Start("AboveApp.exe");
}
```

Initially, the requests count will be less but gradually it reaches 100*100. I'm curious around the requests calculation.

The question is, does the above code generates 10000 requests per second at some point? If not, how many does it generate.

Comment: How would you say that the execution takes one second (to have 10000 req/sec)? I recommend taking a look at tools for perfomance/stress testing. A good one is https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta

Comment: Depending on what version of .NET you are on, you will experience either HttpClient or ServicePointManager connection pooling. There are only so many pooled connections available (by default) so at some point your requests will be queued. As mentioned, use a purpose-built stress testing tool

Comment: @Ahmad that's just the assumption based on the query execution time inside the web service. So we assumed at a time all 100 instances will hit the service. We are generating 100 inside each instance. So, we just multiplied them.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion on the tool. We already have one in place. I'm just curious on the assumption we made is correct or not. Also, this is kind of a stress test if I am not wrong.